# LNPopupController makes UIKeyboard unclickable

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm using LNPopupController (https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController) in my project. I also have an UISearchController for my Table View.

But when I imported the LNPopupController in the project, the UIKeyboard on the Search Controller is not clickable. As soon as I click on a letter on the keyboard, the search controller just gets dismissed. Please let me know the reason for this bug.

Comment: Please post some code showing the relationship between `LNPopupController` and `UISearchController`.  Is the tableView controller (and search controller) contained in the popup view controller?

Comment: @PetahChristian The UISearchController gets messed up even if I only implement the files in the project. Please check this test project out where you'll see what I mean: https://github.com/MarvinNazari/KeyboardProblem

Comment: Hi, see my answer. If you have more issues, please contact me directly or open an issue on GitHub. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been fixed. The issue was, a view was added to an internal controller of Apple, which caused them to return an incorrect tappable view on the keyboard. I changed the logic to more correctly only load the helper view if needed and not necessarily on first layout.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the sample code you provided.

Here's what's going on.

LNPopupController has categories that swizzle (override) methods in `UITabViewController` and `UIViewController`, which affect your view controllers when they load.

The effect you're seeing when the search is active is the same behavior if you clicked the dimmed background (of the tableView above the keyboard) -- the search is cancelled.

In other words, the touch events aren't being handled by the keyboard overlay, but by your view controller, as if the keyboard overlay wasn't even present.

If you want to use the `LNPopupController` project, you should open an issue on GitHub so the maintainer can fix it.